# Parsing HTTP multipart POST using a struct in Rocket

Tags: forms, rust, http-post, rust-rocket

I want to parse a HTTP POST in Rocket using a struct. Upon submitting the form it fails.

I read the [body data](https://rocket.rs/guide/requests/#body-data) example and have this code.

```
#[derive(FromForm)]
struct ConvertFile {
    name: String,
    filename: String
}

#[post("/submit", format = "multipart/form-data", data = "<form>")]
fn submit(form: Form<ConvertFile>) {
    println!("form field: {}", form.get().name);
}
```

I submit using curl:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "name=Claus" -F "filename=claus.jpg" http://localhost:8000/submit
```

and the Rocket console responds with

```
multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------8495649d6ed34d20:
    => Matched: POST /submit multipart/form-data
    => Warning: Form data does not have form content type.
    => Outcome: Forward
    => Error: No matching routes for POST /submit multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------8495649d6ed34d2.
    => Warning: Responding with 404 Not Found catcher.
    => Response succeeded.
```

I want to submit a file hence the `multipart/form-data`. When trying to find the reason, I used a `String` in the struct to make it simpler. So first it responds with a `Matched:` and then no matching routes.

This simpler POST works:

```
#[post("/convert", format = "text/plain", data = "<file>")]
fn convert_file(file: String) {
    println!("file: {}", file);
}
```

I am using the latest nightly Rust with rustup.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure, but have you tried with matching form fields in your `curl` command? You have `file` and `filename` in that `ConvertFile`, not `name` and `filename`.

Comment: The fields in the struct was from an earlier draft auto-saved in SO. So I forgot to modify it with the current curl command when I submitted the question. Thank you for noticing this, I have modified it so it is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rocket does not yet support `multipart` forms.

You can see the tracking issue here: https://github.com/SergioBenitez/Rocket/issues/106

A possible workaround is given in this answer: [How to parse multipart forms using abonander/multipart with Rocket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43424982/how-to-parse-multipart-forms-using-abonander-multipart-with-rocket/43427509#43427509)

Comment: Thank you. But then the example at https://rocket.rs/guide/requests/#forms must be inaccurate?

Comment: no, forms do work, just not the multipart Content-type.

Comment: Hmm, http form post using curl is what I have problems sending. `curl -X POST -f name=claus filename=claus.jpg`.

Comment: this works fine for me: `curl -X POST --data "name=clause&filename=claus.jpg" http://localhost:8000`:

https://gist.github.com/belst/21a6759f183cd031a2cac5846bd4bfbb

Comment: It looks like Rocket tries to match `multipart/form-data` to `multipart/form-data; boundary=....` which obviously fails.  

So as said in the answer, you need to use FromData and not FromForm and parse the body yourself.

Comment: I'm able to upload and save a file using rocket::Data.stream_to_file(). But if I want to sent the filename as part of the form post it seems support for multipart/form-data must be added before that is possible I guess.